# php click if human button before showing page content

Tags: php, button, bots

I need a button on my webpage that must be clicked before the user can see the content , and the buton must be in the same page as the content : like this one :http://imgonion.com/img-516851517c10d.html  (adult ads on it!!) . the button will be for checking if the user is human or robot

Comment: Have you read about captcha?

Comment: it's a page wth a picture ..and peoples should get fast in , not to loose time writing things,then will send them away

Comment: You can load the button first and when the button is clicked load the content using Ajax.

If you dont want to use Ajax then load both button and content but hide the content using CSS(display:none). After button click, un-hide the content using javascript to change CSS.

Comment: Buttons can be 'clicked' automatically. All you need to have is the name of the button and send some dummy x and y variables. It's not ideal and can be automated with the likes of cURL. CAPTCHA would work better, although even I have trouble reading them these days!

Comment: the problem is that .. it registers the visit in mysql , so it needs the button to make sure that is areal person not robot, so if I use CSS , it still loads the whole page including the visit registration

Comment: Bogdan, just yesterday I asked similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17507453/file-download-counter-can-this-antibot-protection-work not sure whether my answer will work 100% all the time. (Also updated a bit its code.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd probably do it similar to [reverse honeypot captcha](http://www.coderrific.com/forum/detail/reverse_honeypot_captcha) - hovering with the mouse over the button should confirm, the user is human. The code could look like this:

html:

```html
<button id="showContext">Show content</button>
<div id="content"></div>
```

javascript/jquery:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var isHuman = false;
    $('#showContext').attr('tabIndex',-1).mouseenter(function(){
        isHuman = true;
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        isHuman = false;
    }).click(function(){
        if (isHuman) {
            $('#content').html('Hello human');
            $.ajax("example.php?isHuman="+(isHuman?'yes':'no'))
            .done(function(data) { $('#content').html(data); })
            .fail(function() { alert("connection error"); });
        } else {
            //alert('das booooot detected');
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NECtq/2/

I am not sure whether this solution will work 100%. Some bots can execute javascript, so the safest way would be to use captcha.
Related discussion here: [Programmatic Bot Detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341695/programmatic-bot-detection)